# some uncertain thread is getting created and not terminating

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have doubt about multithreaded application(ip scanner). When i put large ip range like 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.5.1  and thread limit as 99 .So when i run my application there should be 101 threads running at a time(99 threads(ScannerChild) + Main thread + Scannerthread) and when scanning is done 99 scannerchild and 1 scannethreads would be terminated and only 1 thread should run that time(main thread). But sometimes thread count is going to 102 and after scanning thread count is not coming to 1 it shows threadcount as 2 in task manager. Whats the problem ?

code for Scannerthread
/

```
/Creating constructor of scannerthread
Constructor ScannerThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean );
Begin
    Inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  Freeonterminate:= true;   //Freeonterminate is true
End;

{ScannerThread Thread }
procedure ScannerThread.Execute;
var
    I  :    integer;
    ScannerCh : array  of ScannerChild;  //array of ScannerChild
    IpList : TStringlist; //Iplist as tstringlist
    IPs: Integer;   //ipcount is count of iplist
Begin
  ScannerchCount:=0;  //Initialising scannerchcount as 0
  IpList:=TStringList.Create;//creating stringlist
  IF GetNumberOfIpsInRange(Ip_From, Ip_To, IpList)  Then    //Function call that returns iplist if TRUE
  Begin
    Try
      IF Assigned(LvHosts) Then        //Clearing LvHosts  field
        LvHosts.Clear;
      IPs := IpList.Count; //Ipcount is given value of iplists count
      SetLength(ScannerCh, IPs);  //Setting length of scannerch as ipcount

      I:=0;
        Repeat
          While ScannerChcount > tcount-1 do  //Checking if  is greater than tcount(thread input) by user
            Sleep(30);
          ScannerCh[I]:=ScannerChild.Create(True, IpList[i]);
          ScannerCh[I].FreeOnTerminate:=True;
          ScannerCh[I].OnTerminate:= ScanchildTerminated; // Event scanchildterminated occurs on termination of Scannerch thread
          ScannerCh[I].LvHostname := LvHosts;   //Lhostname is private listview of scannechild
          ScannerCh[I].Resume;
          ScannerChCount:=Scannerchcount+1;   //Incrementing scannerchcounts
          I:=I+1;
          Sleep(20);   //Sleep after each thread is created so that threads will enter critical section properly
       until I = IPs;

       Scannerch:=nil;
      If Assigned(IpList) Then   //Free iplist
        FreeAndNil(IpList);

    Except
      On E: Exception do
       Begin
        ShowMessage('Invalid operation :' + E.Message); //Showexception message

      If Assigned(IpList) Then          //Free iplist
         FreeAndNil(IpList);
      end;   
    End;
  End
  Else
  Begin
   Ipscan.lbResult.caption:='Invalid Ip Range';
   Exit;
  End;
  Repeat                                                                      //Main Thread Waiting For Ip scan Threads to finish
   Sleep(100);
  until ScannerChCount = 0;

End;
```

Scannerchild code

```
Constructor ScannerChild.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; IP: String);
Begin
    Inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  //FCriticalsection := TCriticalSection.create;  //Creating critical section
  IPToScan:=IP;
End;



//Execution procedure for scannerchild
procedure ScannerChild.Execute;
Var
 MainOutput : TListItem;//Listitem variable for adding listitems
 Hostname   : String; //Hostname is declared as string
Begin
 Try
  MainOutput:=LvHostname.Items.Add; //Adding items to mainoutput
  MainOutput.Caption:=IPToScan;
  Hostname := IPAddrToName(IPToScan);
  If Hostname <> EmptyStr Then
  Begin
    MainOutput.SubItems.Add(IPAddrToName(IPToScan));  //Displaying output
  End
  Else
    Mainoutput.subitems.add('No host');
  Finally
  End;

End;

//this event get called when scannerch thread terminates
procedure Scannerthread.ScanchildTerminated( Sender : TObject );
Begin
  ScannerChCount:=ScannerchCount-1; // Decrementing scannerchcount

End;
```

Comment: Do some debugging. Add some diagnostics code to work out where the thread that won't close gets stuck. You do need to learn how to debug. And that doesn't necessarily mean in the debugger. Add trace debugging.

Comment: And you are still accessing GUI control away from the main thread. You've been told about that multiple times. Why ask if you ignore the replies? It is galling for us. Do you think we want to tell you the same thing again and again? We get reward out of helping people learn. If you are incapable of listening then there's no reward for us. Make it worth our while. You are also creating and destroying way to many threads. Create 100 threads and let them work through the tasks until they are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of problems here. I'm going to give you some general advice as well as try to answer your question.

Your accessing of the GUI outside of the main thread is wrong, as we've said before. No need to cover that again, please go back over your previous questions.

The design of your threading is poor. If you would ask a high level question about that we could help you fix it. I'd be happy if you asked a question that allowed me to demonstrate a simple thread pool.

As well as the problems with the threading design, you've got no separation of concerns. No modularity. The threading and the tasks and the GUI code are all mixed in with each other. You need to keep the concerns separate to make the code maintainable and well factored. If you'd only ask us how to design your program rather than to fix the bugs in your weak design we could help you.

All of the calls to `Sleep` and the polling are symptoms of this bad design. There should be no sleeping.

Your code has way too many comments that make it hard to read. There's no need to comment a statement like `i := i+1`. The effect of that is self-evident.

You need to learn how to debug threaded code. The interactive debugger is not so useful. It interferes with the timing of thread execution. Use trace logging to debug such problems. Until you learn how to do this you cannot expect to make progress. I repeat, it is critical that you learn how to debug.

As to the problem you asked about, you have a data race on the `ScannerChCount` variable. So the threads are probably terminating correctly but you are counting them incorrectly.

Use `InterlockedIncrement` and `InterlockedDecrement` to modify it in a thread safe manner. That is both in the child termination code and the controller thread.

You might think this is not needed because `ScanChildTerminated` which decrements the counter is an `OnTerminate` event and so executed by the main thread. But the controller thread code that increments the counter is not executed in the main thread.

If you don't yet know what a data race is, then you have started multi threaded programming too soon. Rather than my explain it I would refer you to the shared data sections of any good text book on parallel programming. Or Wikipedia: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition.

Comment: Thank you i will surely follow this